# Is there a way to resolve a subquery first when using it to prune partitions in Impala

Tags: sql, hbase, impala

I am trying to prune some partitions using a subquery in Impala.

In the query below, where I hardcode the date, I get the expected pruning & impala just reads the relevant partitions.

```
select col1, col2
from table1
where
table1PartitionCol >= '2022-05-01';
```

(Table1) From Explain Plan: **partitions=100/5000 files=100 size=10GB**

However, when I try to get the date from a subquery(querying a different table), the explain plan shows that it reads every partition first, then it will run the subquery & apply it as a filter.

```
select col1, col2
from table1
where
table1PartitionCol >= (select max(partitionValue) from table2);
```

(Table1) From Explain Plan: **partitions=5000/5000 files=5000 size=250GB**

Ideally, it would run the subquery first & then read from the main table. Is there a way to force it to do this? Or some other way to achieve the same results?

Comment: if Impala has to calculate max, it has to traverse through all data. So, i think its not possible to use partition pruning for your qry.

Comment: It's calculating Max on a different, much smaller table. I've updated the question to make that a bit clearer.

Comment: Is data type of table1PartitionCol same in both tables?

Comment: Yeah, both are the same data type of timestamp.